# Weird X and Y of gameobject in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have one problem. X and Y of gameobject are weird. I think that's because its parent isn't main camera. How to set parent without scripting?

Comment: Saying that _X and Y of gameobject are weird._ doesn't give any information on what the actual problem is. Could you try explaining your problem with more details?

Comment: One gameobject is in the middle of main camera and it has got X and Y = 1. Other gameobject is in the corner and it has got X and Y = 1. Other gameobject has -1 X and Y, but its in the main camera too.

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: Firstly, when you ask a question you should be specific, what is your problem? There is no connection between the transform.position of a gameObject and the camera because X and Y are in world-space. making a gameObject child of a camera wont help you in any way. I recommend you learning about the [Hierarchy](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Hierarchy.html) and the [Position of a GameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html)

Comment: So how can I make a game that fit every resolution? Left side of the camera has x=5, when I get Screen. width I get for example 720.

Answer (score 0):

To make a gameObject the child of another, look at your hierarchy and find the gameObject you want to make child, drag and drop it on the other object you want to make parent.

This will make the coordinates relative to the parent.